# How to make an existing branch track a remote branch?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to track an exiting branch to a remote branch using `--track` or `--set-upstream-to`, but got the following error

```
$ git branch --track master origin/master
fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.   
$ git branch --set-upstream-to master origin/master
fatal: branch 'origin/master' does not exist
```

I checked SourceTree and found that it uses `--set-upstream`, but got the following warning

```
$ git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
The --set-upstream flag is deprecated and will be removed. Consider using --track or --set-upstream-to
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Both `--track` and `--set-upstream-to` is not working, Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try `--set-upstream-to`?  In your question you only mention `--set-upstream`.  Also note that you can accomplish the same thing with the `-u` flag to `git push` (`git push -u origin master`).

Comment: For that matter, the `--set-upstream` actually *worked*.  It just first printed a warning: "this old variant is going away, modify your code and/or habits to use the new variant, `--set-upstream-to`".  (The `--set-upstream-to` version takes the parameters in the other order, allowing it to default to "set current branch" like other `git branch` commands.)

Comment: For what it's worth, [here is the documentation for `git branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html).

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think I got it, it will be as the following (used --set-upstream-to + remote name)

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```