# Connect an existing git local branch to an existing gitlab remote branch

Tags: git, gitlab

Here is what i've done:

```
(master)  $ git checkout -b branch3
(branch3) $ ...
(branch3) $ git commit -m "..."
(branch3) $ git push origin branch3
```

As you can see i have forgotten the -u option in git push command.
This means the branch3 local branch won't track remote branch3

What should i do in order to enable this tracking ?

I have tried this:

```
(branch3)$ git branch --track branch3 origin/branch3
```

But it gives me an error because branch already exists ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an existing branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729560/how-to-make-an-existing-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ?

> git branch --set-upstream-to origin/branch3

[Réference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729560/how-to-make-an-existing-branch-track-a-remote-branch)